# How do I resize chart elements?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, charts

I created a pie chart in Excel 2007 and then copied and pasted it into a 2007 PowerPoint presentation.  **I'd like to resize the boxes on the pie charts without resizing the entire chart,** but whether I am in Excel or PowerPoint, it doesn't seem to allow for resizing.  Although the boxes do add what appears to be some sort of resizing element when I click on it, hovering over any of the four points on the box does not change it to a resizing handle.  (I've tried some other things as well, to no avail.)  Is it possible for me to resize these chart elements and, if so, what is the easiest way to do it?  Below is an image of what I'm referring to.

[image]

I did try searching the web first for an answer to this and even this StackExchange, but did not find anything with a solution to this problem.  If I missed something, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the chart is active in Excel, insert a text box and type your data label text into it.  It'll be fully formattable, sizable, positionable.

Otherwise, you'll have to ungroup the chart in PowerPoint in order to modify the text, and once you do that, the connection to the Excel data is broken.  It'll be just a collection of shapes that looks like a chart.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.  Excellent answer, Steve, and thank you.